# Whats Wrong in this Code to generate SelectBoxes Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function myf() {
alert("coming dude");
var numbersString = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var data = numbersString.split(',');

var s = $("<select id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");
for(var val in data) {
    $("<option />", {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
}
s.appendTo("#msj_form");
}
</script>


</head>

<body >

<form  id="msj_form" >

<button id="add" value="add" onclick="myf()">ADD</button>



</form>

</body>

</html>
```

While Clicking on ADD button the selbox is generating but its disappering immediatly..whats wrong in my code

While Clicking on ADD button the selbox is generating but its disappering immediatly..whats wrong in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after your function is called the form is submitted, so what you will need to do is prevent form submission.

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form  id="msj_form" >
    <button id="add" value="add">ADD</button>
  </form>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    function myf(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // <-- make sure to add this
      alert("coming dude");
      var numbersString = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
      var data = numbersString.split(',');

      var s = $("<select id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");
      for(var val in data) {
        $("<option />", {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
      }
      s.appendTo("#msj_form");
    }
    $('#add').on('click',myf);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you'd like to learn more about `preventDefault()`, see here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: <form  id="msj_form" onSubmit="javascript:return false"> even it worked..after i got to know why its failing...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form is getting submitted by default, so to prevent that just use preventDefault() method. Here's my solution. Hope it helps!

```js
function myf() {
alert("coming dude");
var numbersString = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var data = numbersString.split(',');

var s = $("<select id=\"selectId\" name=\"selectName\" />");
for(var val in data) {
    $("<option />", {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
}
s.appendTo("#msj_form");
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#msj_form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  myf();
  
});

});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<form  id="msj_form" >

<button id="add" value="add" >ADD</button>

</form>
```